# Redirect in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to redirect the route when the condition is true. I used 'useNavigate' in react-router-dom. But it's not working.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const navigate = useNavigate();
 if (localStorage.getItem('bearerToken') == null) {
      console.log("true condition");
      navigate('/');  
  }
```

Console data is printed but not redirected.

Comment: Can you provide the full component code?

Comment: export const Dashboard = () => {

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  if (localStorage.getItem('bearerToken') == 'undefined' || localStorage.getItem('bearerToken') == null) {
      console.log("true condition");
      navigate('/');  
  }
}

Comment: What you have included looks like it should run, whether or not it achieves a desirable result depends on what you are trying to achieve and the surrounding code. Can you create a reproducing example of the problem, as well as a detailed description of what you want to happen vs what you are seeing happen?

Comment: I am checking only if the condition is true, it redirects on the home page. I use 'Navigate'. But it's not redirect on home (/) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could add this check to an effect [(`useEffect`)](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect). Currently you are checking for an item in local storage outside of an effect.

With React, you have to set-aside some things you've learned with vanilla JavaScript and make yourself think-in-React. It makes sense to just do an `if` check in your component, but you need to explicitly tell React you want to check for something, whether that be an API call or checking local storage and doing something based on that result.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // check if "bearerToken" has NOT been set in local storage
  if (!localStorage.getItem("bearerToken")) {
    console.log("true condition");
    // it hasn't! let's navigate back to the home page
    navigate("/");
  }
//  this is a dependency array. 
// it tells the effect to run
// if any item in it has changed.
// (we don't have any dependencies
// so we can leave it empty. 
}, []);
```

This will check if the item is not in local storage. If it's not, it will redirect you back to the home page.

Comment: No problem :) I've added some edits to hopefully make it more clear. Please check out the [hooks API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) if you haven't already.